# Installing wxPython in virtualenv under Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wxpython, virtualenv

I am trying to set up a wxpython inside virtualenv. 
As detailed in many places, the easy_install / pip install dosent work as setup.py is not present.

I cam across a description on how to set it up on a Mac, but found no such methods for Linux.

How can this be done on Linux ?

My actual use case is a little experimental. I am trying to get a django project call a wxpython app. This works outside of virtualenv, but the import fails as wx is not installed in virtualenv.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 12.04 the following worked for me:

```
cd <env>/lib/python-2.7/site-packages
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/ .
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx.pth .
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wxversion.py .
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wxversion.pyc .
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried building it from source?  it used to be a long process, but it looks like it's been improved recently.  the instructions are at http://www.wxpython.org/builddoc.php and include the ability to specify an install directory.  it builds fine on linux in my experience, once you have the dependencies installed.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at it today and post here.