# How to install wxPython using virtualenv

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, wxpython, virtualenv

I am trying to begin a new python GUI application and I have decided to use wxPython as GUI because I want a multi-platform one.

The problem is that I want to use virtualenv ( with virtualenvwrapper ) to isolate the environment and be able to reproduce it in other machines where I will work, but i cannot install wxPython.

I have it installed in my ubuntu machine via apt-get but that is not enough

I have searched the web for a solution and i have found ...

- This page http://batok.github.com/virtualenvwxp/ where it is explained a way to hack the virtualenv environment to use the local installation of wxPython. Not the best solution, but it would be a good workaround. The problem is that it is explained for Mac, and I couldnt make it work in my ubuntu.
- Also found this page [Installing wxPython in virtualenv under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977799/installing-wxpython-in-virtualenv-under-linux) where someone ask something similar. I have tried to build wxPython that way with no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

In the end, I have choose wxPython beacuse it is multiplatform and i can use it without license problems, but as i have not started yet i can change my mind if there is another easier to install framework.

Thanks In advance

20110925: Sorry for the delay and thanks for the answers.
I just have tried to install wxpython using buildout and the links given here, but i still have the same problem. It seems as if I need libgtk2.0-dev package to be able to compile wxpython...

So there is any way to install this package locally to the buildout environment?

Thanks again.

Comment: What's the build error when you try building wxPython?

Comment: it seems that gtk is not present ...  checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.0.0... no
*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end I could not resolve this problem.

I want to create a reproducible python environment with all the requirements inside using buildout and/or virtualenv so I could work in any linux system with just virtualenv, python and a C++ compiler installed.

It seems that the only way to do this is to use  buildout cmmi recipes to download and build wxpython and ALL its dependencies. This is a really painful way, and I have no time now.

I have decided to use a workaround: I am going to work  on my ubuntu laptop most of the time, so I have installed wxpython from the repositories and use a wx.pth file to make it available to the virtual environment.

This is not a good solution, but seems the best till now ... so if someone knows any better solution please let me know.

When my python project is more mature, I will turn again to this problem and I will probably try the hard way ...

Thanks for all your answers and comments.

Comment: In case it's not obvious to anyone else, your wx.pth file should contain the path to the locally installed wx: `echo /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode > $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wx.pth`

Comment: I have recently come to a interesting project that could be applicable here http://www.vagrantup.com/

Comment: I know it's not cool to post thanks, but ... thanks mgalgs .. that was SO HELPFUL!!!   _Finally_, thanks to your little comment, I got this to work!  (Yes, I upvoted!)

Answer (score 2):

The solution I ended up using was to install python to my main system:

Then make a symbolic link from the wx in my system python to my virtual environment:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wxversion.py <virtual_env_path>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wxversion.py
```

Where  is the path in my case to a virtual environment named "fibersim" for example is:

```
/home/adam/anaconda/envs/fibersim
```

Then `import wx` worked

Got this from: http://qopml.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/README.txt

Answer (score 1):

[Buildout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/1.5.2) allows your to install different `parts` whose `recipe` code determines how that part is built.  There are [cmmi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.recipe.cmmi) recipes for building stuff with Configure/Make/Make-Install (CMMI).  You can use this to build wxPython locally to the buildout and then create a [python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028765/replicating-reproducing-the-django-development-environment/7038268#7038268) that has that build of wxPython and your own eggs in it's path.

See this [blog post](http://geekscrap.com/2010/01/install-wxpython-in-buildout/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415930/install-wxpython-using-buildout-and-virtualenv/7141207#7141207) for details.

Keep in mind that zc.recipe.egg will also install any setuptools/distribute [console_scripts](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html?highlight=console_scripts#automatic-script-creation) in the buildout's bin directory as well.  See also [mr.developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) for [automatically checking out multiple packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140321/how-to-structure-a-python-projects-with-shared-sub-apps-using-git-and-buidout-wit/7140483#7140483) from VCS and working on them in the same buildout.

Comment: buildout was another tool i were looking some time ago, but it seems more complex to me than pip ... I suppose i will have to fight with those recipes ... thanks for the comment

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally give buildout a try, following the instructions given in the blog entry you post. wxpython is downloaded correctly, but the problem persist...