# How to structure a python projects with shared sub apps using git and buidout without symbolic links

Tags: python, git, git-submodules, buildout, git-subtree

I have multiple **projects** that shares child **apps** with other **projects**.
When working within the **project** directory I want to be able to make changes to the **app**, update it, and pull those updates into the second **project**.

Requirement:

- No use of ***symbolic links*** (my IDE's debugger doesn't work well with them)
- No compiling/rerun a script. I would like to make changes to the **app** without having to rerun a script/buildout.
- Apps must be within the project folder.

Here's the structure:

```
app_one (git repo)
  |-- app_one (actual app uses by projects)
  |   +-- models.py
  |-- README.md
  +-- setup.py

project_one  (git repo)
  |-- project_one
  |   |-- apps
  |   |   |-- app_one
  |   |   |   +-- models.py
  |   |   | -- app_two
  |-- setup.cfg
  +-- setup.py

project_two  (git repo)
  |-- project_two
  |   |-- apps
  |   |   |-- app_one (same app as project_one)
  |   |   |   +-- models.py
  |   |   | -- app_two
  |-- setup.cfg
  +-- setup.py
```

Currently I'm using git-submodules for this; the downside is there is no way to link to a subfolder of a repo. I recently read about subtree, would this work better?

Ideally I would like to use **buildout**, but I haven't found a good way to accomplish this without the use of symbolic links. If there's a way to to do this please let me know.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mr.developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer).  When a mr.developer source is checked out *and* activated, it becomes a setuptools/[distribute develop egg](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#development-mode) in the buildout and so the checkout will be what is used by any scripts (such as a zc.recipe.egg generated python interpreter) in the buildout.

Comment: does mr.developer allow you to work directly with the source? Or is there a compile step? If possible I would like to work directly on the `app` without having to recompile after every change.

Comment: thank you for your response and the link, I'm still trying to grasp exactly what they are saying. By 'compile step' I ment rerunning buildout. Is it necessary to rerun buildout after every change? In case it's relevant this is for an app engine project so the source code, E.g. `app_one` has to be within the `project_one/apps` directory

Comment: You need to re-run buildout only if you *change which eggs* are activated/in develop mode.  IOW, as long as all the eggs you are making code changes to are *already* activated, you do not need to re-run buildout.  This is *exactly* what mr.developer is for.  Keep in mind that some setup.py changes, such as adding new dependencies would require re-running buildout.

Comment: @Kyle: Note that mr.developer has an `update` command, which will update all source-control directories under it's control. `bin/develop up` is the same as `git pull`, `svn up`, etc. in all your mr.developer-managed dependencies.