# How can I install wxPython 3.0.1.1 in Python 2.7 virtualenv on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, virtualenv, ubuntu-14.10

The following procedure fails. Am I missing something?

- Install various Ubuntu packages (prerequisites for compilation)
- Get http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython-src-3.0.1.1.tar.bz2
- Uncompress to `wxPython-src-3.0.1.1/`
- Create new virtualenv called `test`
- Activate `test` virtualenv
- In terminal, from `wxPython-src-3.0.1.1/`:

  ```
  ./configure --prefix=/home/username/.virtualenvs/test --with-gtk2 --enable-unicode --with-opengl
  #lots of output, confirms "Configured wxWidgets 3.0.1 for `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'"

  make install
  #lots of output, confirms:
  # The installation of wxWidgets is finished.  On certain
  # platforms (e.g. Linux) you'll now have to run ldconfig
  # if you installed a shared library and also modify the
  # LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or equivalent) environment variable.

  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/.virtualenvs/test/lib
  # don't run ldconfig since that is a system tool, not appropriate for virtualenv?

  cd wxPython
  python setup.py install
  # lots of output, starting:
  # WARNING: WXWIN not set in environment. Assuming '..'
  # Found wx-config: /home/username/.virtualenvs/test/bin/wx-config
  #     Using flags:  --toolkit=gtk2 --unicode=yes --version=3.0
  # Preparing CORE...
  # Preparing STC...
  # Preparing GLCANVAS...
  # Preparing GIZMOS...
  # running install
  # etc
  ```

The final command fails with:

```
src/gtk/_core_wrap.cpp:20407:7: note: ‘arg3’ was declared here
   int arg3 ;
       ^
src/gtk/_core_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_Image_SetAlphaBuffer(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
src/gtk/_core_wrap.cpp:3747:13: warning: ‘arg3’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
             if (ALPHASIZE != self->GetWidth() * self->GetHeight()) {
             ^
src/gtk/_core_wrap.cpp:20474:7: note: ‘arg3’ was declared here
   int arg3 ;
       ^
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: found similar questions re not-quite-the-same versions/environments which did not apply - tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/20170771/236081 which had no effect

Comment: this may be caused by http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/hardening-wrapper

Comment: Had the same problem on Debian 8.3 with wxPython 3.0.2.0. The accepted answer worked (though I'm not sure what these warnings were or meant in the first place).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used `python setup.py install &> ~/error.txt` to pass on the error messages to knowledgeable colleague who identified that C compilation was using the `-Werror=format-security` flag. This version of wxPython (and maybe others) cannot compile with that flag.

My `$CPPFLAGS` and `$CFLAGS` environment variables were empty.  It turns out that this flag is triggered by [hardening-wrapper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/hardening-wrapper).

So, I overrode the flag by invoking the final step as follows, and wxPython was installed successfully:

```
CFLAGS=-Wno-error=format-security CPPFLAGS=-Wno-error=format-security python setup.py install
```